# Left column takes 50% of website not a div

Tags: html, css

`.left-navbar` should be in the place when scrolling, `.fullPage-left-column` I wanna add scroll to read an article but `fullPage-right-column` should be also in the place when scrolling.

there's `position: fixed` in `.left-navbar` and `fullPage-right-column` to stay in the place. But in this case left colum and right column has 50% but `.fullPage-left-column` takes 50% of website not available place.

```css
.fullPage {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: red;
}
.fullPage .left-navbar {
    width: 88px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: green;
}
.fullPage .fullPage-left-column {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
.fullPage .fullPage-right-column {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullPage">
    <div class="left-navbar position-fixed"></div>
    <div class="fullPage-left-column"></div>
    <div class="fullPage-right-column position-fixed"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.fullPage .fullPage-left-column` was set to have a `width: 50%`, so this will set the `width` of that `div` to 50% only. Instead, try setting it to `width: auto`.

Comment: I set width: auto; and it takes 100% now

Answer (score -1):

```css
.fullPage {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: red;
}
.fullPage .left-navbar {
    width: 88px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: green;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.fullPage .fullPage-left-column {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 88px;
    background: yellow;
}
.fullPage .fullPage-right-column {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullPage">
    <div class="left-navbar position-fixed"></div>
    <div class="fullPage-left-column">Left</div>
    <div class="fullPage-right-column position-fixed">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed and _why_ you changed it.

Comment: is this the expected result? I hav updated the code to show the left to take only width that it's supposed to take instead of 50%